# iOS YouTube api v3: uploaded video url

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api

I want to get the URL of the YouTube uploaded video. It is possible to get the YouTube uploaded video URL in **api-v2** using `(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)videoEntry;`.
Can anyone please tell me how to do the same in **api-v3**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There no direct way of getting url, following is the answer!

```
self.uploadFileTicket = [service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,GTLYouTubeVideo *uploadedVideo,NSError *error) {
                   NSString *videoURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", uploadedVideo.identifier];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the method in this [sample](https://github.com/NSRover/YouToobAPI/blob/master/YouToobAPI/YouTubeHelper.m):

```
- (void)uploadPrivateVideoWithTitle:(NSString *)title description:(NSString *)description commaSeperatedTags:(NSString *)tags andPath:(NSString *)path
```